# Django-cms: How to add side navigation

Tags: django, django-cms

I am using latest Django-cms(3.5.0), I have installed it through djangocms-installer. And now I want to add extra navigation tree since I don't want it being nested inside Main navigation.

I want to add it like this:
[image: https://imgur.com/2IXwgnY]

How can I add it?

The following apps are installed:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'treebeard',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'filer',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'djangocms_column',
    'djangocms_file',
    'djangocms_link',
    'djangocms_picture',
    'djangocms_style',
    'djangocms_snippet',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'djangocms_video',
    'dslendavasite',
)
```

Comment: What do you want that tree to contain? I'm fairly sure it's not possible, but equally can't imagine a use case for that.

Comment: I would be used for a navigation on the sidebar which is only displayed on some templates and i wanted to separate it from main tree. So its more user friendly to the editor.

Comment: Yeah you can't do that. The tree itself has the option to include/exclude pages from the menus & then you can dictate with the menu tags at which levels of pages get displayed in a menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **menu_tags** inside your main html template, go to your mainproject/templates then edit base.html. Follow the [instruction](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/navigation.html).